# getting invalid ouput after std::move of an element from std::list

Tags: c++, stdlist, stdmove

I'm trying to understand about std::move. In my code I'm moving an element from `std::list<struct Data>` where `struct Data` internally contains two `std::string` fields, but I'm not getting expected output. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

struct Data {
    std::string topic {};
    std::string msg {};

    Data(const std::string& topic, const std::string& msg) {
        this->topic = topic;
        this->msg = msg;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::list<Data> data_list;
    data_list.push_back(Data("A", std::string(1000, 'a')));
    data_list.push_back(Data("B", std::string(1000, 'b')));
    data_list.push_back(Data("C", std::string(1000, 'c')));
    data_list.push_back(Data("D", std::string(1000, 'd')));
    data_list.push_back(Data("E", std::string(1000, 'e')));
    
    while (!data_list.empty()) {
        std::cout << (void*)&data_list.front() << "\n";
        Data&& d1 = std::move(data_list.front());
        data_list.pop_front();
        std::cout << d1.topic << ", " << d1.msg << "\n";
        std::cout << (void*)&d1 << "\n\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You store a reference to the first element and then pop the first element. You get a dangling reference and undefined behavior.

Comment: You can't move this specific instance. But if you do as NathanOliver did in his good answer, the implicit move-ctor will move the memory managed by the two string members to the new instance (instead of copying the memory). Yeah, `std::move` is not really intuitive to use :)

Comment: Consider using `emplace_back()`, like so: `data_list.emplace_back("A", std::string(1000, 'a'))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is you are not actually moving anything.  When you call `std::move`, nothing is actually moved.  What it does do is converts the lvalue that you have into an rvalue, so that it can then be move constructed or move assigned from.  That's not what you are doing here though.  You use

```
Data&& d1 = std::move(data_list.front());
```

which has `d1` as an rvalue reference, meaning no move again, it's just a reference to the object in the list.  When you pop that element, your reference is now refering to an object that no longer exits, and using it has undefined behavior leading to the output that you are seeing.  If you want to move the element, you need

```
Data d1 = std::move(data_list.front());
```

and now `d1` will use `Data`'s implicit move constructor to move the list element into `d1`.

Comment: `Data d1 = std::move(data_list.front());` statement doesn't a create a copy of the `std::list` element?

Comment: @Harry No, it moves `data_list.front()` into `d1`.  Your data already does.  `std::string` is a class type.  It has a move constructor as well.  Since it does, the compiler generated move constructor of `Data` is also going to call the move constructor of the strings.  This might clear things up for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics

Comment: what if struct Data in turn contains another user defined struct as field which doesn't implement neither move constructor nor move assignment operator?

Comment: @Harry Just saw your updated second comment.  In that case, it falls back to a copy if it can't be moved.  If it also can't be coped, then you would get a compiler error.

Comment: I've one last doubt, assume that the internal struct field contains say 10000 integer fields. How to efficiently implement a move constructor or move assignment operator in that case, because I'm feeling in this struct of 10000 integer fields case there is no way to move but to copy the entire 10000 integers, even if move constructor or move assignment operator are implemented. Am I correct about this?

Comment: Yes, things like `int` don't benifit from moving, it's still a copy.  Where moving gives you a boost, is when the class points to its data (like a vector).  When you have that, then moving just means copy the pointer to the destination, and then set the source to null so it no longer points to the data.  This lets you "move" the pointed to data from one object to another.